# Linking to external URL with appended tracking code in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I wish to have a unique http link to an external URL, pulled from my JSON data,  from within the detail pages of my app.

I have installed the inappbrowser plugin that currently works with a static url going to apple.com. However, I wish to use a product specific link url from my JSON data. Here is the [JSON data](https://sheetsu.com/apis/v1.0/d0b1d8ecfc4f), it is the "aw_deep_link" I wish to use.

How can I link to an external URL pulled from an Angular expression using my Buy Button on the detail page and then append some Google Analytics tracking code to the end of the URL?

Here is the Google Tracking Code I want to append:

```
?utm_source=app&utm_medium=android
```

**[Here is the Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3mI8qaYz1ld1F1H9bxe9?p=preview)** currently working with a static url on the detail pages.

DETAIL.TS

```
openUrl() {

        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            let browser = new InAppBrowser("http://www.apple.com",'_blank');
            // let browser = new InAppBrowser("www.apple.com$?utm_source=app&utm_medium=android",'_blank');
            // let browser = new InAppBrowser("{data.aw_deep_link}",'_blank');


        });
}
```

DETAIL.HTML

```
<button (click)="openUrl()" ion-item>Buy Now</button>
```

Here is a similar concept used for Twitter pages in the Ionic Conference App

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/pages/speaker-list/speaker-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't taking a url param in openUrl function.

```
<button (click)="openUrl(data.aw_deep_link)" ion-item>Buy Now</button>

openUrl(url) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        let browser = new InAppBrowser(`${url}?utm_source=app&utm_medium=android`,'_blank');
        });
}
```

Comment: Bingo! I'll tick your answer, many thanks. Just for info why is the $ required in the 'let browser' line?

Comment: ${url} is a new feature in javascript ES6 (which typescript uses) that allows you to concat a string better. read more here https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#es6-template-literals